# Прочитать символ с экрана по заданным координатам

Tags: linux, c, terminal

Есть некий legacy код на С, реализующий многоуровневое меню в терминале linux. Для перехода по вложенным менюшкам используется такой алгоритм:

1. Есть некий буфер, содержащий 24x80 символов.
2. Новый экран отрисовывается в нем
3. Если это не первый экран, то предыдущее состояние сбрасывается во второй буфер
4. Содержимое буфера выводится на экран

Мне этот код надо сейчас немного доработать, но вот этот механизм с отрисовкой в буфер просто вымораживает. Всякие прелести жизни типа printf'ов сразу идут лесом.

Хочу переделать таким образом:

1. Высчитывается область отрисовки нового подменю
2. Конкретна эта область скидывается в небольшой локальный буфер
3. Отрисовывается подменюшка, сразу на экран
4. При возврате - возвращаем кусок экрана из буфера обратно

Собственно вопрос. Возможно ли реализовать пункт 2?

Ну и в целом, если есть какие нибудь мысли как можно подобное поведение организовать по человечески, то буду рад.

PS curses не предлагать. Полностью перелапачивать под него не сдюжу.

Comment: printf идет лесом, потому что Вы не знаете о sprintf

Comment: @KoVadim Нет, не по этому. Лесом он идет, поскольку там эта тряхомудия с буферами организована совершенно адским образом. Вот кусочек даже выложил http://www.govnokod.ru/20400

Comment: Реализовать можно как хотите.  ESC последоваетльность в терминале работает. Поэтому можно переписывать хоть по одному символу.

Comment: @Yaroslav вопрос не в том, как перерисовывать - это, слава богу, проблем не вызывает. Вопрос как буферизировать кусок экрана, что бы возвращать на место содержимое перекрытое новым окном после его закрытия.

Comment: @rjhdby Вы хотите узнавать что находится на терминале ?

Comment: @Yaroslav Вроде так вопрос и сформулировал. Но это скорее от безысходности, типа "А вдруг можно!?". Боюсь все же придется ковыряться с буферизацией, от этого становится печально.

Comment: @rjhdby Было бы красиво. Но  то что ушло в /dev/ttyX , уже не вернуть. Вам нужно постоянно сохранять состояние терминала.

Comment: @Yaroslav надо будет погуглить на тему проксирующего tty. Что то вроде перенаправления stdout на свой обработчик, в котором сохранять состояние и дальше прозрачно в tty

Comment: **Есть некий буфер, содержащий 24x80 символов** - меня смущает слово "некий"... Поскольку вы не желаете использовать ncurses, возникает сильное подозрение, что с устройством отображения (дисплеем) какая-то нестандартная ситуация. Я как-то делал отображение меню на устройстве для таксистов. Там был экран 32 х 4 символов. Подозреваю, что у Вас схожая ситуация - так ? Я там выдавал строки не через tty, а через GPIO и всю буферизацию делал сам.

Comment: @rjhdby Так то ядро и является временным буфером для tty, и можно сделать модуль ядра который будет хранить текущее состояние экрана, НО нужно реализовать механизм получение этого буфера.

Comment: @Sergey устройство отображения - клиент putty. "Некий" он потому, что самописный. И все бы ничего, если бы у разработчика руки росли из плеч, но к несчастью там треш, угар и содомия.

Comment: `ncurses` ваше всё. Да, вопрос читал внимательно.